# How to find all emails Mail thinks are Junk?

Tags: macos, mail.app

How do I search for messages that Mail.app thinks are Junk emails?

I would like a search query that finds all the of the Junk emails without requiring them to be moved into a Junk folder. I am running macOS 10.12.

Here is a sample image showing a message marked as Junk. Look at the message left hand side top of the image.

[image: Screenshot of Mail]

Answer (score 2):

In the Preferences of Mail.

You can choose how Junk mail needs to be handled. If you activate 'Move it to the Junk mailbox' it will be moved to the Junk box automatically.

It is the Junk list with all the emails that are seen as junk email by Mail.

[image: Mail Preferences, Junk settings]

Comment: But how do I list them out? without moving them to Junk mailbox? Is there something that I can type into the search box to find all emails that Mail thinks are junk? More over I see a lot of emails marked as junk but not moved to the Junk Folder, even though I have enabled the setting.